# mysql_num_rows does not work, but it does work on another query

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I have two ways of getting the players username, one when they login and another when they login using an email. Yet when they login as a new player, it connects to Minecraft.net database and checks if the username/password/email is correct, if so, it will add them to our database without the password.

But I can't seem to get the second MYSQL query to work, there is no mysql errors or connection errors, but the rows keep on coming out as 0 when there is 1 row inside.

```
if (strpos($_POST['username'],'@') === false) {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$username'");
                $ign_exists_check = mysql_num_rows($res);
                $username_exists_check = 0;
                if(!$res) die ('Unable to run query1:'.mysql_error());
            }
            else {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username'");
                $username_exists_check = mysql_num_rows($res2);
                $ign_exists_check = 0;
                if(!$res2) die ('Unable to run query1:'.mysql_error());
            }
            die($username_exists_check . $ign_exists_check);
            if ($usernamea_exists_check == 0 && $ign_exists_check == 0)
                {
```

Comment: is this correct ? `strpos($_POST['username'],'@') === false` => `user_email='$username'` it seems you set the condition wrong.

Comment: Let me see if it work..

Comment: Doesn't work, it logs me in using the email as the username, but its suppose to log me in as the username in the database in the same row as the email.

Comment: Yes I know. I just copied from your current source code. I meant the condition is probably wrong so changing `===` to `!==` could work.

Comment: Fixed it :) Thanks. I must of changed it when looking at PHP documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got no errors and 0 rows back then the query "worked", it simply didn't find any rows that matched the criteria.
What you need to do is to echo out the query thus:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username'";
```

You will then see precisely what it is searching for. Indeed, take the echoed query and try running it against the database using something like phpMyAdmin.

However, something I DO notice is that your logic says that, if you do NOT find an @ in the posted username field, then lookup the username in the user_email column and if there IS an @, then look it up in the user_name field. Maybe your check should be:

```
if (strpos($_POST['username'],'@') !== false) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems upside-down.

When there is no @'s in the username, you're querying `user_email`
there are also too much repetitions in your code

```
if (strpos($_POST['username'],'@') === false) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$username'"
    $username_exists_check = 1;
} else {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$email'"
    $username_exists_check = 0;
}
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$user = mysql_fetch_array($res);
if ($user) {
    $ign_exists_check = !$username_exists_check;
} else {
    $ign_exists_check = $username_exists_check = 0;
}
var_dump($row,$username_exists_check,$ign_exists_check);
```